# Recursive cypher query for a Neo4J database

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Imagine having a database with 3 main nodes:

- Account
- Email
- Phone number

Every accounts that share the same email should be unique. Similarly, every accounts that share the same phone number should be unique. So if we want to drag out all of accounts that should be unique, we gonna need to do something like:

```
MATCH (:account) -[:has_email]-> (:account) -[:has_phone]-> -[:has_email]-> (:account) -> ...
```

And the query go on forever. Do we have a built-in solution in Neo4J for this type of problem ?

Many thanks and good day everyone.

Comment: You can use variable length patterns. https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/patterns/#cypher-pattern-varlength

Comment: You can take a look at the WCC algorithm in Neo4j GDS

Comment: Can you fix your sample query? It makes no sense.

Comment: The sample query is just a brief idea about the thing that I'm trying to implement, sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

I create some data samples below:

```
CREATE (a1:Account {name:'acct1'}),
(a2:Account {name:'acct2'}),
(a3:Account {name:'acct3'}),
(e1:Email),
(e2:Email),
(e22:Email),
(e3:Email),
(p1:Phone),
(p2:Phone),
(p3:Phone),
(p32:Phone),
 (a1)-[:has_email]->(e1),
(a1)-[:has_phone]->(p1),
(a2)-[:has_email]->(e2),
(a2)-[:has_email]->(e22),
(a2)-[:has_phone]->(p2),
(a3)-[:has_email]->(e3),
(a3)-[:has_phone]->(p3),
(a3)-[:has_phone]->(p32)
```

[image]

Below is the query to get all accounts with non-unique email or phone.

```
MATCH (a:Account)-[:has_email]-(e:Email), (a)-[:has_phone]-(p:Phone)
WITH a, size(collect(distinct e)) as ecnt,  size(collect(distinct p)) as pcnt 
 WHERE ecnt>1 or pcnt>1
RETURN a.name, ecnt as duplicate_email_cnt, pcnt as duplicate_phone_cnt
```

which should return account2(duplicate email) and account2(duplicate phone)

Sample result:

```
    ╒════════╤═════════════════════╤═════════════════════╕
    │"a.name"│"duplicate_email_cnt"│"duplicate_phone_cnt"│
    ╞════════╪═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╡
    │"acct2" │2                    │1                    │
    ├────────┼─────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
    │"acct3" │1                    │2                    │
    └────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```